# How to implement a TCP server that receives and sends data in two processes?

Tags: networking, process, c, sockets

I am trying to implement a TCP server using C in Linux. I want this server to accept incoming data forever from multiple clients and at the same time send some data back to each connected client in every 3 seconds.

My problem is I don't know how to properly do `send()` in a different process than the one handling the client.

What I am doing is at the beginning of the program do a `fork()` and do

```
while (1) {
  sleep(3);
  // compute and `send()` data to each connected peers
}
```

in child process, do

```
sock = create_socket();
while (1) {
  client_sock = accept_connection(sock);
  if (fork() == 0) {
    close(sock);
    handle_client(client_sock);
    exit(0);
  }
  close(client_sock);
  // clean up zombies
}
```

in parent process. `handle_client()` is simply `recv()` data in a infinite loop. Because `send()` and `recv()` are executed in different processes, I couldn't use the socket file descriptors to `send()` in parent process. What do I need to do in the parent process to do the `send()`?

Comment: If the accept is done in the parent and then the fork is done then both client and server share the client socket and can send/recv on it. It will not work with SSL sockets though since the SSL state is kept in user space, i.e. each process has a separate state. Anyway, I think this is a bad design from start and you should instead use either threads or event based programming and thus keep everything within a single process.

Comment: Event-driven programming is new to me but I will definitely have a look at it. Thank you!

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Basic Apache works exactly has you said, by forking, and handles SSL just well... So it is not necessarily a  bad design. It has its benefits and drawbacks like any other one.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: Apache does not uses one process for receiving and another for sending data on the same socket as the OP likes to do. It uses the same child process for sending and receiving, which is perfectly fine also with SSL since only a single process contains the SSL state.

Comment: I believe the OP just did not specify its problem properly, because without specific constraints, I see no reason to do reading and writing in separate processes; so it is maybe just because not knowing how to handle `accept()`.

Comment: You do know there's plenty of libraries that will make your life much easier for this exact type of work, such as libuv (which is portable and used by node.js) or facil.io (which offers pub/sub features allowing you to publish messages to your clients)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution using Linux `epoll` and `timerfd` (error handling is omitted):

```
int start_timer(unsigned int interval) {
  int tfd;
  struct itimerspec tspec;

  tspec.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
  tspec.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
  tspec.it_interval.tv_sec = 3;
  tspec.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

  tfd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0);
  timerfd_settime(tfd, TFD_TIMER_ABSTIME, &tspec, NULL);
  return tfd;
}

void epset_add(int epfd, int fd, uint32_t events)
{
  struct epoll_event ev;
  ev.data.fd = fd;
  ev.events = events;
  epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &ev);
}

int main()
{
  int epfd, tfd, sock, nfds, i;
  struct epoll_event events[MAX_EVENTS];

  /* create new epoll instance */
  epfd = epoll_create1(0);

  tfd = start_timer(TIMER_INTERVAL);
  /* socket(), bind() and listen() omitted in create_socket() */
  sock = create_socket(PORT_NUMBER);
  /* add sock and tfd to epoll set */
  epset_add(epfd, tfd, EPOLLIN);
  epset_add(epfd, sock, EPOLLIN | EPOLLET);

  for (;;) {
    for (i = 0; i < nfds; ++i) {
      if (events[i].data.fd == tfd) {
        /* handle timer notification, it's run
           periodically with interval TIMER_INTERVAL */
      } else if (events[i].data.fd == sock) {
        /* accept() incoming connections,
           set non-blocking,
           and add new connection sockets to epoll set */
      } else {
        /* recv() from connection sockets and handle */
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This program was helpful https://github.com/eklitzke/epollet/blob/master/poll.c and I added timerfd to the epoll set so the server *keeps listening and receiving data* and at the same time can *send data to the clients periodically*.

Answer (score 3):

You have *three* levels of processes, a parent, a child, and many grandchildren.  Get rid of these levels, and do not fork *at all*; instead using an event-driven model in a single process.

In rough pseudo-code (translate to your preferred language):

```
listening_fd = create_socket();

EventQueueOfSomeKind q;   // kqueue()-style
q.add_or_update_event(listening_fd, EVFILT_READ, EV_ENABLE);
q.add_or_update_event(3, EVFILT_TIMER, EV_ENABLE, NOTE_SECONDS);

FDToContextMapOfSomeKind context_map;

EventVector event_vector;     // vector of kevent-like things

while (1) {
  q.wait_for_events(&event_vector);    // kevent()-style

  foreach e <- event_vector {
    switch (e.type) {
      case EVFILT_READ:
        if (listening_fd == e.fd) {
          client_sock = accept_connection(e.fd, SOCK_NONBLOCK);
          q.add_or_update_event(client_sock, EVFILT_READ, EV_ENABLE);
          q.add_or_update_event(client_sock, EVFILT_WRITE, EV_DISABLE);
          context_map.add_new_context(client_socket);
        } else {
          // Must be one of the client sockets
          if (e.flags & EV_EOF) {
            context_map.remove_context(e.fd);
            q.remove_event(e.fd, EVFILT_READ);
            q.remove_event(e.fd, EVFILT_WRITE);
            close(e.fd);
          } else {
            recv(e.fd, buffer);
            handle_client_input(&context_map[e.fd], buffer);
          }
        }
        break;
      case EVFILT_WRITE:
        if (has_queued_output(context_map[e.fd])) {
          send(e.fd, pull_queued_output(&context_map[e.fd]));
        } else {
          q.add_or_update_event(client_sock, EVFILT_WRITE, EV_DISABLE);
        }
        break;
      case EVFILT_TIMER:
        foreach client_sock,context <- context_map {
          push_queued_output(&context, computed_data(context));
          q.add_or_update_event(client_sock, EVFILT_WRITE, EV_ENABLE);
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

I have glossed over partial `send()`s and `recv()`s, write-side shutdown, and all error handling but this is the general idea.

## Further reading

- https://github.com/mheily/libkqueue
- Jonathan Lemon. [`kqueue`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man2/kqueue.2). *OpenBSD System Calls Manual*.
- Jonathan Lemon. [`kqueue`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/kqueue.2.html). *Darwin BSD Calls Manual*.  Apple corporation.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I had no idea what `kqueue` is but I am glad to know that there are great tools out there waiting for me to learn. I am checking the docs and will come back later. Thx

Comment: @iamlazynic - note that `kqueue` is the BSD approach (also available, albeit slightly broken, on macOS). Linux uses [`epoll`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) (which is supposed to be newer). IMHO, `kqueue` is better designed (hence, [the suggested library](https://github.com/mheily/libkqueue)), but if you're only targeting Linux than you might as well use the actual system calls.

Comment: @JdeBP. I adopted the event-driven approach but use `epoll` instead because I think it is a more Linux way. `timerfd` is well suited for my requirements because it allows specifying an interval. I will not accept your answer because I would like to post my current implementation using `epoll` and `timerfd` but thank you very much for your hints.